# Booting an old XP HDD into a new computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, boot

I am building a new PC and want to have my old PCs HDD in it as a second unit and boot to it whenever needed. I've heard that the odds of it actually booting are very low. But some say it can be possible. So heres my questions and concerns:

Will it boot?
If not what can I do to make it boot?
If I try to boot it without doing anything will it corrupt the entire drive so it doesn't even work on the old PC ever again?

Any tips will be helpful.

It is currently running XP Pro and the motherboard I will have it on is either a H97 or Z97, both support windows 8/10

Comment: You might be able to boot off of it, if the hardware is similar....Windows, especially XP, likes to panic and BSOD if it doesn't like hardware changes.  The easiest thing to do would just have it as a secondary drive for storage etc. and not try to boot into the old OS.  You might be able to perform a repair install on your XP drive connected to the new computer, and get it to boot that way (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978788).  If you do this, make sure to unplug any other drives, just to make sure they are not modified, formatted, overwritten, etc.

Comment: Would it be better to install windows 10 on the drive before booting it into the new pc? Why a repair install? How can I unplug drivers, wouldnt that cause me to ex: stop seeing the screen right after unplugging my video driver and installing the NVDIA one? If it doesnt work, how can I undo all the changes I made to the driver settings?

Comment: A repair install on XP should re-initialize the drivers and HAL....basically it will reload the OS on the new hardware without wiping out any of your data.  Your profile etc. should still be intact.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I did a main board and CPU upgrade but before I replaced the hardware I installed the drivers for the new hardware.

that being said I'm aware that your hardware is a lot newer than you OS, best thing you could do would be to do a complete backup and then install the drivers for the new hardware and finally plug it all in and give it a go.

And no I highly doubt that doing this will render your HDD unusable within you old system.

[Reference](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1872439/hdd-mobo-cpu.html)

Comment: Agreed: This will not render the HDD unusable.  However, you may have severe issues with drivers.  (Win98 could often work well; I've heard WinXP may be harder, but that might be because WinXP is usually more customized with specific drivers rather than generic/compatible drivers).  Expect to boot to safe mode.  Expect to need to add drivers.  Expect that process may not work well; you may find this difficult/impossible.  However, there is not significant danger to the HDD's functionality, or even its current data, if things are done right.  (Clearly mistakes can cause problems.)

Comment: Now I just need someone whos actually done it to guide me through step by step. Thanks for the input. Do you also think that upgrading windows will make it easier to work?